# How to call a function for all query result?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to call a function for all objects resulted from `where` query

Something like this:

```
User.where('email LIKE ?', '%@domain.org').skip_confirmation!
```

What's the right way to do so? to call the function for all objects resulted from the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an way to call method for an arel

```
User.where('email LIKE ?', '%@domain.org').each(&:skip_confirmation!)
```

If you want to more optimized code then move the query into an `scope` then call as following

```
scope :by_email, -> {where('email LIKE ?', '%@domain.org')}  

User.by_email.each(&:skip_confirmation!)
```

Answer (score 1):

`User.where('email LIKE ?', '%@domain.org')` returns an arel relation, but you can call most Array methods on it, so you can do:

`User.where('email LIKE ?', '%@domain.org').each &:skip_confirmation!`

If you expect your query to returns tons of results, use `.find_each` instead.